# Does $R \subsetneq \mathbb{N}$ contradict '$f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow R$ is one-to-one and onto'

Tags: elementary-set-theory

There is a paradox I can't resolve. If we take the set of natural numbers $\mathbb{N}^0$. We could take the element $0$ as our starting position and reference to all other elements by defining a successor function $S(n)=n+1$ (i.e. $1$ is $S(0)$, 2 is $S(S(0))$ and so on).

If we take the set of all references it would look like $R=\{S, SS, SSS, SSSS, ...\}$. Now it seems obvious that for every element in $\mathbb{N}$ (without 0) there is a corresponding element in $R$ ($\forall x \in \mathbb{N}:x \in R$). Or in other terms, there is a function $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow R$ that is one-to-one and onto.

However, one can rewrite the set $R$ by (notationally) replacing $S$ with $1$. $R$ would then look like $R=\{1, 11, 111, 1111, ...\}$. In this case $R$ is the set of all natural numbers only composed of a single digit. Of course this is only a subset of all natural numbers ($R \subsetneq \mathbb{N}$).

Does $R \subsetneq \mathbb{N}$ contradict '$f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow R$ is one-to-one and onto'? Where is the mistake in the above argument?

Comment: $R\subsetneq \mathbb{N}$ only says that the natural inclusion map is not a bijection. There is no reason (a priori) to believe that there can not be a bijection between a set and it's proper subset. Of course, in this case the set has to be infinite.

Comment: Why do you make it so complicated? Why don't you just define $R=\{1,2,3,4,\dots\}$ and ask "Does $R\subsetneq\mathbb N$ contradict '$S:\mathbb N\to R$ is one-to-one and onto'?"

Comment: There is no paradox. Every non-finite subset of $\Bbb N$ is a bijective image of $\Bbb N.$ Functions between infinite sets are very different from functions between finite sets.

Comment: See the little book "Stories About Sets" by Vilenkin.

Comment: Hmm.. yes.. true! I guess what I was confusing is that there is no index assigned to the elements of the set. So every proper non-finite subset of an infinite indexed set $A$ is not a bijective image of $A$?

Comment: It turns out that there is a natural way to index the elements of a subset of $\mathbb{N}$: the smallest element is indexed with $1$; the next smallest with $2$; and so on...

Comment: yes, however this "natural" index is not bound to the element in the set, it is the position in a set. An element bound index does behave completely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure if this answers your question, but you can indeed form a bijection $f: \mathbb{N} \to \{1,\ 11,\ 111, \ \dots\}$ via:
$$
f(n) = 10^{n-1} + 10^{n-2} + \ \cdots \ + 1 = \sum_{i= 0}^{n-1}10^i
$$

This is an injective mapping, because $f$ is monotone, and surjective because for each number $l =\sum_{i= 0}^M10^i \in R$, $f(M+1) = l$.

Edit: also, as someone else has said, in general $A \subsetneq B$ does **not** imply $\#A < \#B$. For example, $\mathbb{Z}$ is in a bijective correspondence with $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Why not just $f: \Bbb N \to R$ defined $\forall n \in \Bbb N$ by 
$$f(n)=\underbrace{1 \dots 1}_\text{$n$-many}?$$

Comment: That's exactly what the function I defined does, I just formalized the concept of "n times 1" so that it's well defined.

Comment: Ahh, okay. Good answer!

Answer (score -2):

There is no contradiction because $\Bbb N$ is infinite and infinite sets can biject with its proper subset (assuming axiom of choice).

Comment: don't need AofC for $\mathbb N$ to have a bijection to a proper subset

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I knew someone would point out that. I'm talking about infinite sets in general.

Comment: just kinda puts the cart before the horse. One generally shows an arbitrary infinite set has such a bijection by using choice to show a countable subset